# Working with JQuery animate and "this" selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, this

I'm working on what I thought would be a simple chunk of code, trying to dynamically (using 'this') animate div blocks to scale (zoom) to the size of the parent container (section tag) on click.

My HTML:

```
    <section>

    <div id="project"></div><div id="project"></div><div id="project"></div>

    <div id="project"></div><div id="project"></div><div id="project"></div>

</section>
```

My JavaScript:

```
    $("#project").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.75,
            width: 100%,
            height: 100%
        }, 5000, function() {
    });
});
```

Both Jquery and Jquery UI are linked correctly from Google Libraries (so says my console), my console also tells me that there is a syntax error with an unexpected ",", however I am taking this syntax straight from JqueryUI.com. Any help is appreciated!

Additionally, I want to be able to dynamically select all other divs except the currently clicked div and remove them from the DOM (using display:none), just so it looks cleaner, but I don't know how to go about 'selecting' them in my code...

Thanks all! :)

Comment: ID must be unique. Use class for multiple elements

Comment: What is the line number of the syntax error?

Comment: Ok, will test using classes. As for the error, it's on the line with the 'width' property, which makes me even more confused.

Comment: Using classes did not change anything, code is now $(".project")

Comment: How would I revert this back after the animation has occurred using another click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing quotes around 100% so your code will be correct like this

```
$("#project").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.75,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
        }, 5000, function() {
    });
```

and please use unique IDs

Edit:
for using classes you can use something like that

```
$(".project").click(function() {
            $(".project").css({'display':'none'});
            $(this).css({'display':'block'});
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 0.75,
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%"
            }, 5000, function() {

        });
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. As for IDs, I needed to change to classes to that I could use the "this" selector. Does anyone have any ideas on how to selector every OTHER div so that I can set their display:none? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to dynamically select all other divs except the currently clicked div and remove them from the DOM (using display:none), just so it looks cleaner, but I don't know how to go about 'selecting' them in my code...

```
var $project = $(".project");
$project.click(function() {
  var thisDiv = this;
  $project.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem!==thisDiv) $(elem).css('display', 'none');
  });
  $(thisDiv).animate({
    opacity: 0.75,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  }, 5000, function() {});
});
```